# Why does my program for identifying palindromes always rejects the input?

Tags: c

I made a program to find if a entered string is palindrome or not palindrome but it always says that its not a palindrome

```
#include <conio.h> 
#include <graphics.h> 
#include <string.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i,len,halflen,flag=1;
    char str[50];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(str);
    len=strlen(str);
    halflen=len/2;
    for(i=0;i<halflen;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=str[i+halflen])
            flag=0;
        break;

    }
    if(flag)
        printf("It is a Palindrome.");
    else
        printf("It is not a Palindrome.");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Indented code -- this code is a good demonstration of its necessity.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin by correcting one of the bugs in the question, you'll make it hard for people reading the answers to grasp the bugs they are addressing

Comment: • Don't define `main` as a function returning `void`. It must always return `int`.
• Check whether the call to `gets` actually succeeded.
• Never use `gets(str)`, prefer `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)` over it, since otherwise there will be *undefined behavior* when a user enters a too long string.
• Instead of doing the computation in the `main` function, write your own function `int is_palindrome(const char *str)` and put the computation into that function.

Answer (score 10):

Your central comparison is flawed:

```
if (str[i] != str[i+halflen])
```

This isn't comparing the two characters you think it is.

Try entering "HelloHello" into your program, it will say it is a palindrome!

You need to compare these two:

```
if (str[i] != str[len-i-1])
```

(and fix the braces, as suggested in the other answer)

Comment: That should be `if (str[i] != str[len-1-i])`, If you do not add the -1 it will compare the first character to the '\0' at the end and will fail for all but empty strings.

Comment: wait a second ! does strlen count the \0 too ? :S

Comment: @fahad, no.  `strlen` gives the number of chars before the `\0`.

Comment: @fahad, the problem is that `"Hello"` is `['H','e','l','l','o',0]` and has length 5, as expected. If you start comparing element `0` with element `len-0` you will compare the `'H'` with the 6th element (at position 5), which is `'\0'`.

Comment: Yes all, sorry, it should be str[len-i-1]

Answer (score 6):

To give you a clue I've done some tidier indenting of a bit of your code:

```
for(i=0;i<halflen;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=str[i+halflen])
            flag=0;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: And this is why the grey-beards use braces everywhere, even when some people might think they don't need them.

Comment: This is a problem, but not the whole problem

Answer (score 4):

You can also use STL to check if a given string is palindrome using function `equal`. Lets say you have an `std::string` named `x`, then the following function call determines if x is palindrome

```
equal(x.begin(), x.begin() + x.size() / 2, x.rbegin());
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you want something like...

```
    if(str[i]!=str[strlen (str) - i - 1])
    {
        flag = 0;
        break;
    }
```

The `break` needs to go in the `if` block otherwise it will always get executed. Initialising `flag` at some point would be a good idea, too. If I might be permitted an observation, ALWAYS enclose the if-block and else block in curly brackets even if there is only one statement; it would save you several of the problems you've got here.

Later - edited per Mr Rodriguez' comments below.

Comment: Again the problem of the off-by-one. You must offset the right term with a -1 for this to work.

Comment: You're right. Closing the brackets correctly would have been good as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the [2005 version of myself](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/TheChannel9Team/Gary-Daniels-and-Evan-Goldring-Mock-whiteboard-problem/?CommentID=96335#98244):

```
bool isAlphaNumeric(char c)
{
    return (iswalpha(c) || iswdigit(c));
}

bool isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    /* A man, a plan, Anal Panama!!! */
    if(*str == '\0')
    {
        return false;
    }

    int len = strlen(str);
    if(len <= 1) return true;

    char *start = str;
    char *end = start + len - 1;

    while(start < end)
    {
        if(!isAlphaNumeric(*start))
        {
            *start++;
            continue;
        }
        if(!isAlphaNumeric(*end))
        {
            *end--;
            continue;
        }
        if(towlower(*start) != towlower(*end))
        {
            return false;
        }
        *start++;
        *end--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There are a few stray `*` in the solution that make it less readable than it should... `*start++`, `*end--` should be `++start` and `--end` (the extra dereference can be easily elided by the compiler knowing that it is not used, but for us humans it only adds to confusion --or that´s my belief.  -- I have corrected the `"` => `'\0'`, as that was surely a copy error.

Comment: Never use the character-testing functions like `iswalpha` or `towlower` with plain `char` as the argument. It leads to *undefined behavior*. Better use `isalnum((unsigned char)c)`. And why do you use `iswalpha` at all? That function is for wide characters, and you just pass it a simple character.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This was from 5 years ago, which was 4 years after the last time I'd regularly used C/C++. Thanks for fixing the errors, too. I copied it from my blog, and Wordpress screwed up a lot of the code with its automatic formatting, turning "--" into a long dash, and removing a few other characters. Thought I'd caught them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isPalindrome(char* str) {
    char* s = str;
    char* e = str;
    while(*e) e++;
    --e;
    while(s < e) {
        if(*s != *e) return false;
        ++s; --e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter solution (C++; identical line count for C):

```
bool is_p(char const * const str, ptrdiff_t n)
{
  if (n < 1) return false;

  auto p = str, q = str + n - 1;
  while (*(p++) == *(q--))
    if (p >= q)
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `C`-flavored solution : )

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(const char* s) {
    const char* p = s;
    while (*p != '\0') ++p;
    while (s < p) if (*s++ != *--p) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[100], b[100];
    printf("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome\n");
    gets(a);
    strcpy(b, a); 
    strrev(b); 
    if (strcmp(a, b) == 0) 
        printf("The string is a palindrome.\n");
    else
        printf("The string isn't a palindrome.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a better way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "Enter your text: ";
    cin >> input;
    transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (input[0] == input[input.length()-1])
        cout << "Palindrome";
    else
        cout << "not palinrome";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: This is a C question, not C++.