# find a palindrome, doesn't work with fgets

Tags: c

i want to see if a word/phrase is a palindrome or not. i have to use fgets and not gets etc...
with gets my code works but with fgets it doesn't. anyone knows why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{

    int i,j,len;
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    len=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);

    for(i=0,j=len-1;i<j;i++,j--) {
        while (str[i]==' ') i++;
        while (str[j]==' ') j--;
        if( str[i] != str[j] ) {
          printf("NO\n");
          return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("YES\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, does it compile for you? Also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285432/to-find-if-a-given-string-is-palindrome-or-is-not-palindrome?rq=1

Comment: Look at the string in the debugger. Then step through your code. Inspect the variables. The answer should be immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work with `fgets` because it keeps the trailing `\n` with the string; `gets` does not do that.

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

To fix this, adjust the length to account for the trailing `\n` mark: go to the end of the string, and move back until you see a non-`\n` character.

Comment: i see, thanks!
if i do :
len=strlen(str)-1;
it works. we just give simple works/phrases like : abcba,dad,anna,never odd or even etc...
so i changed this and and it works.
thanks ;)