# strcmp does not return 0 on equal strings in c

Tags: c, strcmp

So im making a program that checks if a word is a palindrome but when it comes to comparing the final strings at the end even if they are the same i get a -1 result edit: copy pasted the exact same code i used

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[50];
    char test[50];

    int ret;

    printf("Enter word or phrase to compare ");
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
    strcpy(test,input);

    strrev(input);

    ret = strcmp(test,input);

    if(ret == 0)
        printf("\n this is a palindrome ");
    else
        printf("\n this is not a palindrome");
}
```

For input i used "ala" which i know is a palindrome i get the result

```
this is not a palindrome
```

[Demonstration on IDEONE.](http://ideone.com/s2MaiJ)

Comment: `test` is never initialised.

Comment: See [removing the newline from fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776) .

Comment: The newline doesn't matter for this particular purpose, because it is copied to `test` along with the rest of the string.

Comment: The program, as presently given, does not for me exhibit the problem described.

Comment: can't reproduce. vote to close.

Comment: Try putting a newline at the end of the prompt `printf("Enter word or phrase to compare ");`

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/PLdbua)

Comment: what's your input string?

Comment: You have not posted the code where you have the alleged "get a -1 result". Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: You really could have saved us all alot of time if you had showed the real code from the beginning. Leaving out the call to `strrev` changed the whole question.

Comment: @user3386109 the newline would indeed be a good guess if in fact the code were not working.  But the code present in the question at the time I made the comment worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `strrev` without stripping off the newline from your input obtained from `fgets`. This causes your reversed string to have the `newline` at the beginning of the string, which would cause a mismatch even if you intended to provide a palindrome as the input.

While there are various ways to achieve this, one way would be to look at the last byte of your input, and see if it is a newline character. If it is, remove it.

```
if (fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin) == NULL) {
    /* todo: ... handle error ... */
    return 0;
}
len = strlen(input);
if (input[len-1] == '\n') input[--len] = '\0';
strcpy(test,input);
```

Comment: Actually, this question was [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20183687/315052).